# Is ANT copy task case-sensitive?

Tags: ant

I am trying to copy a file inside my ANT build script. For example the below copy statement -

**`<copy file="myfile.txt" tofile="mycopy.txt"/>`**

My doubt is- if by mistake/chance the physical file name becomes myFile.txt or MyFile.txt or MYFILE.txt, will the above statement still work??

I am unable to find any relevant documentation for the same. Please clarify if you are aware. Thanks.

**UPDATE**- I am aware that if I use `fileset`, I will be able to use '`casesensitive`' attribute of fileset. But, I'm just using the '`file`' type.

Answer (score 1):

At the bottom of the copy page, it mentions if a file with a different case exists in windows, it copies over it. This to me indicates it's OS dependent, hence linux would be case sensitive and Windows not so much.

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html

Comment: That seems interesting. But I was telling about the case-sensitivity of source file name, not the destination file name.

Comment: I think it'll be the same due to overall consistency. Have you tried testing it with a sample file.

Comment: I am going to try on a Mac system.

Answer (score 1):

As you've already said, `fileset` allows you to control case-sensitivity.

When using the `file` attribute the task's [`copySingleFile`](https://github.com/apache/ant/blob/df33426bf23dd97171dc3e0e7cb85de87d421bce/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/Copy.java#L618) method kicks in which uses `File#exists` to determine whether there is anything to copy. `exists` is case-sensitive on Unix-like systems and insensitive on Windows. So using the `file` attribute is platform dependent.

Given your doubt you probably want to use something like

```
<copy tofile="mycopy.txt">
  <fileset file="myfile.txt" casesensitive="false"/>
</copy>
```